# How to convert an entire pandas dataframe into a pandas series (all rows and columns)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, autocorrelation

I would like to convert a pandas dataframe of 11 columns and 9000 over rows into a series and to plot its autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation function, which take in a series as its input. 10_before represent lag = 10, 8_before is lag = 8 and interest is where lag =0. Each row represents 1 data.

I would like to ask if it is possible to convert my df into a series or is there any other methods to get the acf and pacf? Thank you!

Manage to get an series like this, how can i plot acf and pacf using this?

```
0     [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 8.0, ...
1     [15.0, 1.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0,...
2     [2.0, 1.0, 100.0, 1.0, 5.0, 2.0, 10.0, 1.0, 1....
3     [3.0, 3.0, 7.0, 5.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 14.0, 1.0,...
4     [10.0, 1.0, 7.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 4.0, 2.0,...
5     [1.0, 42.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 67.0, 2.0...
6     [1.0, 13.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0,...
7     [1.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 15.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0,...
8     [3.0, 1.0, 13.0, 2.0, 15.0, 30.0, 14.0, 2.0, 1...
9     [1.0, 4.0, 2.0, 15.0, 30.0, 30.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1....
10    [42.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 25.0, 67.0, 16...
dtype: object
```

My code is as follow:

```
a= np.array([trade_10before,trade_9before,trade_8before,trade_7before,trade_6before,trade_5before,trade_4before,trade_3before,trade_2before,trade_1before,trade])
a = a.tolist()
a = pd.Series(a)
plot_acf(a)
plot_pacf(a)
plt.show()
```

Got this error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-a6cd38689337> in <module>()
     70     })
     71 df_acf1_past = df_acf1_past[new_order]
---> 72 df_acf1_past = pd.Series(df_acf1_past.iloc[:,:])
     73 print(df_acf1_past)
     74 plot_acf(df_acf1_past)

/usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    262             else:
    263                 data = _sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy,
--> 264                                        raise_cast_failure=True)
    265 
    266                 data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)

/usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
   3275             raise Exception('Data must be 1-dimensional')
   3276         else:
-> 3277             subarr = _asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)
   3278 
   3279     # This is to prevent mixed-type Series getting all casted to

/usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py in _asarray_tuplesafe(values, dtype)
    400             except ValueError:
    401                 # we have a list-of-list
--> 402                 result[:] = [tuple(x) for x in values]
    403 
    404     return result

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 11 to array axis with dimension 9683
```

[image: dataframe]

Comment: A series is by definition a 1D object. So not sure how you want to transform the 11 dimension dataframe into the 1D series? Or is the 11D the result of the lagging that you are doing?

Comment: Hi @nick my objective is to obtain an acf and pacf plot, so if there is anyway I can do it I will be glad, since plot_acf and plot_pacf take in a series as input. Perhaps we can try the 11D result?

Comment: Sorry to belabour the point. Just to confirm 100%: Your data observations are 11 dimensional?

Comment: It's more like each column represent 1 lag. So column = 'interest' represents the observation I am interested or when lag = 0. 10_before is 10 observations before the interested observation (lag=10) etc.

Comment: Yes okay that is what I thought. And you are using the `statsmodels plot_acf` function? https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf.html

Comment: Yes I am using from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf AND 
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_pacf

Comment: You should simply call `plot_acf(df.interest)` or `plot_pacf(df.interest)`. I.e. your series is the variable of interest. The routines in statemodels do the calculations to get the lags for you so don't do this first.

Comment: @nick Thank you! But does it take into consideration the values in 10_before to 1_before?

Comment: From what I understand of our discussion, `10_before` to `1_before` are the lagged valued of `interest`. (i.e. 10_before = interest_at_time_steps_10_in_the_past). This can calculated from just the one series when you pass that into the function. So, the answer is yes it does :)

Comment: Because, I am not finding the correlation between the values along interest column, but finding the correlation betwen interest column with 10_before to 1_before column

Comment: Haha sorry! but it is not the case of 10_before = interest_at_time_steps_10_in_the_past! because I am only interested to find the auto correlation if the value in column 'interest' fulfil a certain condition